# Show that $Y$ has constant regression with respect to $X$ and/but that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Tags: probability, regression

The joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is given by

$$ f(x,y) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1/2 & \quad \text{$|x|+|y|\leq 1$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$$

Show that $Y$ has constant regression with respect to $X$ and/but that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

So far I have that the marginal density function for $X$ is $$f_{X}(x)=\int_0^{1-x}\frac{1}{2}dy=\frac{1-x}{2} \quad \text{for $0<x<1$}$$ and the marginal density function for $Y$ is $$f_{Y}(y)=\int_0^{1-y}\frac{1}{2}dx=\frac{1-y}{2} \quad \text{for $0<y<1$}.$$ Also, $$\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)=\int_0^{1-x}y(1-x)dy=-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^3 (=\mathbb{E}Y?).$$ I don't exactly know what I'm trying to show. Does anyone know where to go from here?

Comment: Your region of integration is wrong. The distribution is along the edges of a square with vertices at $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)$.

Comment: For non-independence, informally if you know $X$ you know $Y$. For a more formal proof, you might show that $\Pr(0\le X\le 1/3)$ is non-zero, as is $\Pr(0\le Y\le 1/3)$, but the probability they are **both** in this interval is $0$.

Comment: I think the joint density function wants $1/2$ for $|x|+|y|\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the input. I don't know how to choose integrals though.